# Left mouse button click detect on winform using Reactive extensions IObservable on events

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Just started reading on Reactive extensions. I am trying to watch a simple left mouse button click on my winform. Meaning anywhere there is a click (on any control on the form including the form) I just want to display a message "Click detected". So far I have

```
var mouseDown = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(frmMain, "MouseDown");
//missing code please fill here 
mouseDown.Subscribe(() => Debug.WriteLine("left click detected.");
```

I know the first line will detect any mouse event. I want just the left mouse button click. Please post working code so I can understand this better. Right now in a tailspin with buzzwords I have never used before like .takeuntil etc.. 
Further refining my question. What is the Rx equivalent of

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    Console.Writeline("{0}", m.Msg);
}
```

That should observe every observable mouse or keyboard event.
thank you

Comment: The Rx pre-release documentation has just been posted today:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242982(v=VS.103).aspx.   You should probably take a look at that, and see the Rx Forums.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I'm not sure if thats working code (can't try it now) but it should get you started.

```
var mouseDown = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(frmMain, "MouseDown")
                      .Where(x => x.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed);

mouseDown.Subscribe(() => Debug.WriteLine("left click detected.");
```

Comment: thanks Chris.    var mouseDown = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(this,"MouseDown") Compiler error on this. I am trying this code on a button click event on a form. this refers to the form. Intellisense does not show MouseButtonEventArgs so I am trying MouseEventArgs. I have now downloaded & installed the rx sdk (vs 2010, .net 4.0), added the system.reactive ref. There is only one book on Reactive extensions on Amazon. That too not yet released. for now i am studying from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596158/good-introduction-to-the-net-reactive-framework

Comment: iam gueesing i dont see MouseButtonEventArgs because iam not using wpf. This issue is winforms related. thanks